# c# localisation with 'Resx' file, 'ResourceManger->GetString" function always considers 'English' Culture

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, localization, xamarin.forms

I am localising a Xamarin Forms project.

I am using C#'s `Resx` file to achieve it.

Everything is working fine in the Sample project which I downloaded as well as the Demo project which I have created. But in the Actual project of mine, both `AppResources.xyzKey` and `resourceManager.GetString(xyzKey, anyCulturePassed)` returns a value from the English `Resx` file.

I have even tried sending hardcoded Spanish culture to the `resourceManager.GetString()` function.

```
const string ResourceId = "projectName.Resources.Resx.AppResources";

public static string Localize(string key, string comment)
{
    //var netLanguage = Locale ();

    // Platform-specific
    ResourceManager temp = new ResourceManager(ResourceId, typeof(L10n).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    Debug.WriteLine("Localize " + key);


    string result = "";
    try
    {
        //Dynamically detecting culture is commented for testing.
        //CultureInfo ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocale>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();

        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es");

        result = temp.GetString(key, ci);

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = key; // HACK: return the key, which GETS displayed to the user
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {

        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

In spite of this is always picks the Value from the English `Resx`file.

These are my resource files:

[image]

I have ensured that the respective resource files are loaded by printing them;

```
    var assembly = typeof(AppResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()) 
        {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
        }
```

This is the output:

[image]

Surprisingly, on the same platform it works just fine in the Sample as well as the Demo project.

Comment: looks like the files have the wrong build action and / or custom tool. build action needs to be `Embedded resource` and CustomTool `ResXFileCodeGenerator`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out only the English `Resx` file was set as `Embedded Resource`.

Hence, even on printing the `GetManifestResourceNames()`, it printed the name of the `Resx` file but it was only for the English version of the file.

To fix this, when you create a new `XML` file as `Resx` for a new language,

Right click on the file --> Build Action --> Set as Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Resource files are influenced by the executing thread's culture. Did you try changing the running thread such as;

```
newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR");         
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
```

Comment: If this doesn't work and Sample as well as the Demo projects work please share your project. The problem may be in settings of the project.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the GetString() method which is internally used by the partial class of the Resx files does not pick the culture from the executing threads culture. It accepts the culture as a parameter.